# Detect browser back button in Salesforce visualforce page

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce, apex, sfdc

How to control or detect or show pop up on browser back button click.
I have two visual force pages on second vf page save we redirect to Record detail page. If user clicks on browser back button then it return to vf page. How to stop or any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Pleas find the link here:[Implemented and Tested Solution to Pre](https://harikrishnaratikindi.wordpress.com/2016/11/23/prevent-browser-back-button-click-on-visualforce-page/)